# Static variable declaration in JNI

Tags: c, image, camera, java-native-interface, static-variables

I have a C Image algorithm code in JNI C part.

I`ve done the data acquiring from camera in JNI and it works fine.

However, when I tried to use my image algorithm for further use. and it crashes on phone test every time without any error.

the situation in phone test : the App starts normally , after about 0.5 secs, and app crashed(aborted).

I`ve debug for several days. and I found out it was two variables use to store my ROI coordinates(x,y) cause this problem, because these two variables should memorize the x,y coordinate of last frame and new frame continuously, so I declared these variables as Static
for example:

```
 static  unsigned int XXX =0, YYY =0;
```

these variables are declared in my image algorithm. not in the native C, native C just do  giving the parameters and calling the algorithm.

The weird thing is ,when I delete the "Static" part of these declaration of XXX,YYY, the App goes fine. but the value of XXX,YYY would not be memorized, so it would be useless for my algorithm.

can anyone please tell me how this happening? or some better solutions for my work thanks :)

Comment: I should name it 'interrupt' ,the app starts normally and then it suddenly close. and jumped out to background

Comment: Well making a pair of 'int' variables static isn't going to have that effect, is it? Something else must be different, or else the result of the computation becomes invalid in some way that indirectly causes this behaviour. You need to investigate further.

Comment: i found some logcat that tells my WIN death.. before that , just some declarations of camera parameters. and then the WIN death log came out. thanks for response.I`ll investigate more details